# Separate numbers from text in R

Tags: regex, r, text, gsub, grepl

I have some text:

```
text="blablabla 400ft blablabla"
```

I'd like to get:

```
"blablabla 400 ft blablabla"
```

The commands:

```
unlist(strsplit(text,split="[^0-9]+"))
gsub("[^0-9]+", " ", text, fixed = FALSE)
```

only return 400.

I'd like to say to gsub: replace every number you find in the text by the same number plus a whitespace at the beginning and at the end. How can I do that?

Comment: According to your description you are looking for `gsub("([0-9]+)", " \\1 ", text)`, though it will always add a space in front and behind, even if not needed.

Comment: That's right, in the case of numbers that are already separated from text. I can always strip the extra white space later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 gsub('([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)', '\\1 \\2', text)
 #[1] "blablabla 400 ft blablabla"
```

Also works with multiple instances

```
 text1 <- paste(text, text)
 gsub('([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)', '\\1 \\2', text1)
 #[1] "blablabla 400 ft blablabla blablabla 400 ft blablabla"
```

Comment: I think you can simplify this to just `gsub('(\\d+)(\\D+)', '\\1 \\2', text1)`

Comment: @user2835597  I didn't try the `whitespace at the beginning` as it will create an additional space

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the comments.  I am now actually thinking about the  description in the OP's comments as I previously didn't notice it.

Comment: Yes, I've already made that comment under the question. I think the OP is confused. Not to mention he said that your solution works perfectly.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner with gsub and regular expressions, sorry. I said the initial solution proposed by akrun worked perfectly because I executed the command and it gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use look-arounds if there are some instances where you want to separate digits from 'ft', say, and not otherwise:

```
text="blablabla 400ft blablabla 400notft"

gsub('(?<=\\d)(?=ft)', ' ', text, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "blablabla 400 ft blablabla 400notft"
```

as opposed to `gsub('([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)', '\\1 \\2', text)` which will separate regardless of what comes next:

```
gsub('([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)', '\\1 \\2', text)

# [1] "blablabla 400 ft blablabla 400 notft"
```

and you can also use other conditions:

```
text="blablabla 400ft blablabla 400notft blablabla 400in"

gsub('(?<=\\d)(?=ft|in)', ' ', text, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "blablabla 400 ft blablabla 400notft blablabla 400 in"
```

or say you need to add whitespace between letters and digits while preserving the rules above:

```
text2 <- 'blblabla 400ft blablaba400ft 400 blabla 400notft blah400notft'
gsub('(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\\d+)|(?<=\\d)(?=ft|in)', ' ', text2, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "blblabla 400 ft blablaba 400 ft 400 blabla 400notft blah 400notft"
```

Comment: I think you have a point, but I am not sure whether this is only specific to `ft`

Comment: @akrun I added for feet and inches. I think that covers everything, yes :}

Comment: `[1] "blblabla 400 ft blablaba400 ft 400 blabla"` should there be whitespace before middle 400?

Comment: Anyway, never mind, the OP didn't describe it correctly.

Comment: `text2 <- 'blblabla 400ft blablaba400ft 400 blabla 400notft'; gsub('(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\\d+?)|(?<=\\d)(?=ft|in)', ' ', text2, perl = TRUE)` my knowledge of regex is nearing its end

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to say to gsub: replace every number you find in the text by
>   the same number plus a whitespace at the beginning and at the end

```
gsub("([0-9]+)", " \\1 ", text)
```